# Tag cleanup: [bubble]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

The tag [bubble](/questions/tagged/bubble) appears to be used in at least four ways:

- As a synonym for [bubble-sort](/questions/tagged/bubble-sort) (examples: [Bubble Sort in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224301/bubble-sort-in-mips), [Output Bubble Sort results to an array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049236/output-bubble-sort-results-to-an-array-in-java))
- As a synonym for [speech-bubble](/questions/tagged/speech-bubble) (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240144/how-to-make-the-thought-bubbles-tail-part-using-core-graphic-in-iphone)
- As a synonym for [bubble-popup](/questions/tagged/bubble-popup) (example: [how to loop javascript for creating bubble popup form more than 1 content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848288/how-to-loop-javascipt-for-creating-bubble-popup-form-more-than-1-content))
- As a synonym for [bubble-chart](/questions/tagged/bubble-chart) (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066833/is-it-possible-to-add-a-back-hatch-style-to-the-bubbles-in-a-microsoft-chart-bub)

The first use appears to be by far the most common, so [bubble](/questions/tagged/bubble) should perhaps be made into a synonym for [bubble-sort](/questions/tagged/bubble-sort) and the other incorrect uses be retagged appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just need to go through and retag them all appropriately. A synonym is not helpful at all. The term bubble is ambiguous and already included in all the tag names. Typing in "bubble" in the tag box will already bring up [bubble-sort](/questions/tagged/bubble-sort) as the first option (after the [bubble](/questions/tagged/bubble) tag is destroyed), so adding a synonym to it achieves nothing.

**Update:** Everything has been retagged appropriately. Most of them were just removed. Many got sent to either [bubble-sort](/questions/tagged/bubble-sort) or [event-bubbling](/questions/tagged/event-bubbling), and a few I sent to [bubble-popup](/questions/tagged/bubble-popup) and [bubble-chart](/questions/tagged/bubble-chart). I've killed off [speech-bubble](/questions/tagged/speech-bubble) as it's just a plain meta tag.